# Rake paperclip:refresh on Heroku - Time out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, timeout, paperclip

I had a problem with my attachments upon changing some configurations for Paperclip -> [Paperclip configurations | Old Attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048735/paperclip-configurations-old-attachments)

The Answer was : `rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Screen`

On Localhost it worked just fine. But upon deploying to Heroku and S3 i got a warning and the rake was aborted!

```
rake aborted!
Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the 
timeout  period. Idle connections will be closed.

AWS::S3::Errors::RequestTimeout Your socket connection to the server was not read 
from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
```

I have no idea how to fix this, anyone an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the region for AWS?  I've seen this before when I was using a European region for AWS and hadn't defined it.

There's a [good article](http://davidjrice.co.uk/2010/10/26/amazon-s3-european-bucket-issues-paperclip-attachment_fu.html) on this that goes into depth about this issue.  It would be worth a shot.

Comment: The Region i defined was `US Standard`. A similar problem appeared here but they say, with paperclip 3.0.2 it was solved -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/9967301/1609496